# What does a capacitor parallel to a resistor do in the feedback of op-amp circuits?

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrated-circuit, feedback

[image: Schematic showing an opamp with negative feedback and a 0.01µF cap parallel to 10MOhm resistor in the feedback line]

What is 10Mohm for?
What would happen without it?

Comment: This could have been solved by this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier

Answer (score 3):

The circuit is an integrator and in the absence of an input voltage, the op-amp output *should* stay held at the voltage it acquired prior to the input becoming zero. However, nothing is perfect and the op-amps input imperfections will tend to push or pull the output towards either power rail (but slowly). To this end, the 10 Mohm resistor will try and counter that by discharging the capacitor slowly. Now the op-amp output will gradually drift back to centre-rail.